# Why is Zev Vendel bother about reading these ground cables?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-bourne-legacy

In *The Bourne Legacy (2012)*, in a room, Col Eric Byer and his team are presented with a box
full of files:

> Zev Vendel: **Is anybody reading these ground cables**?
>
> INGRAM: Look, how wide are we digging?
>
> Col Eric Byer: What do you mean, "how wide?" Just get me everything.
> Treadstone, Blackbriar, Outcome, LARX. All the beta programs.

Why is Zev Vendel bother about reading these ground cables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Because that's his job.

He and the team are tasked with finding out the extent of the problem with the beta programs so reading all the relevant information including the "ground cables" would be an essential part of establishing what information is relevant to the problem.